# Keyerror from celery task delay

Tags: django, celery

Following the [celery getting started with Django instructions](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), I am able to run tasks, but not run the same task asynchronously using delay().

I added the following requirements to my Django project:

```
celery==4.3.0
redis==3.3.11
django-celery-results==1.1.2
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
django-cors-headers~=3.1.0
```

Created this celery.py in the pop_model project directory:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pop_model.settings.local')

app = Celery('pop_model')

# namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
# should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Inserted this code in the project **init**.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Configured cors in the project settings and added these settings:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db' # defined in django_celery_results

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

I can start redis, then run celery using these commands:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=pop_model.settings.local
celery worker -A pop_model --loglevel=info
```

In a python3 shell, I get these results:

```
>>> from pop_model.celery import debug_task
>>> debug_task()
Request: <Context: {'args': (), 'kwargs': {}}>
>>> task=debug_task.delay()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/janee/.virtualenvs/pop-model/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'backend'
```

I don't know how to resolve the missing `backend` key as CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND is defined in the settings file.

Comment: is this shell a normal python shell of is it one started with `./manage.py shell`?

Comment: This is a normal shell. I did export export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE before running it though.

Comment: You solved the puzzle! Running in `./manage.py shell`, everything works!

Comment: @pablo-albornoz, please add your solution so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between a normal Python shell and `manage.py shell` is that it exports your settings module (`project_name.settings`) in the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.

If you run the same interpreter with the proper environment variable you should see no change. Then, it may be that your `pop_model.settings.local` path is not returning a proper settings module for your app to latch on, or you're using a modified `manage.py` script (for development environment separation, I suppose) where the settings module is properly loaded.

You should be able to call your function using

```
./manage.py shell
```

from your project directory, using the same intepreter of your virtual environment. This could also work because the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE needs a path that is present in the interpreter's search path (more on that [here](https://diveinto.org/python3/your-first-python-program.html#importsearchpath)) and you could be calling the interpreter from another directory.